# How can I call component method from async function?

Tags: angular, typescript

My code:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      this.ParseFacebookLoginStatus(response);
    });
  }

  ParseFacebookLoginStatus(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
  }
```

My console is outputting `ERROR TypeError: this.ParseFacebookLoginStatus is not a function`.

I just guessing here that getLoginStatus is async and this in the result context insnt my TestComponent? How can I return to my TestComponent with a proper callback?

Comment: Thats it @Sheki, works like a charm! Thanks! Add it as answer and ill accept it :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help! (by the way, the problem has nothing to do with async or sync it has to do with the context of `this`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function instead of the keyword `function` like

```
FB.getLoginStatus((response)=>{
```

or save `this` in a variable and use that instead of `this` before calling `FB.getLoginStatus` like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let $this = this;
  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    $this.ParseFacebookLoginStatus(response);
  });
}
```

otherwise the keyword `this` is not referring to the component but to the new function.

So the problem has nothing to do with `async` or `sync` it has to do with the context of `this`.